# Problem with including my own library in STM32

Tags: c, stm32

Program works well without including "menu.h" even if i use function from this library in main.c , but when i include this library and build the program i get many errors that don't say anything.
I would be grateful for help

Problem looks like that (but with 38 lines which look the same like the first three):

```
/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.10.1/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.linux64_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./Core/Src/menu.o:/home/dawid/Desktop/Programing and other/GITHUB/STM32_Usefull_Codes/STM32F334R8_Program/Debug/../Core/Inc/menu.h:26: multiple definition of `menu4'; ./Core/Src/main.o:/home/dawid/Desktop/Programing and other/GITHUB/STM32_Usefull_Codes/STM32F334R8_Program/Debug/../Core/Inc/menu.h:26: first defined here
/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.10.1/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.linux64_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./Core/Src/menu.o:/home/dawid/Desktop/Programing and other/GITHUB/STM32_Usefull_Codes/STM32F334R8_Program/Debug/../Core/Inc/menu.h:25: multiple definition of `sub_menu2_5'; ./Core/Src/main.o:/home/dawid/Desktop/Programing and other/GITHUB/STM32_Usefull_Codes/STM32F334R8_Program/Debug/../Core/Inc/menu.h:25: first defined here
/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.10.1/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.linux64_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./Core/Src/menu.o:/home/dawid/Desktop/Programing and other/GITHUB/STM32_Usefull_Codes/STM32F334R8_Program/Debug/../Core/Inc/menu.h:28: multiple definition of `menu6'; ./Core/Src/main.o:/home/dawid/Desktop/Programing and other/GITHUB/STM32_Usefull_Codes/STM32F334R8_Program/Debug/../Core/Inc/menu.h:28: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:64: STM32F334R8_Program.elf] Error 1
"make -j8 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

main.c :

```
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "i2c.h"
#include "tim.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "servo.h"
#include "lcd_i2c.h"
#include "menu.h"
//#include "common.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
struct lcd_disp disp;
uint8_t count;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
 * @brief  The application entry point.
 * @retval int
 */
int main(void)
{
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

 /* USER CODE END 1 */

 /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

 /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
 HAL_Init();

 /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

 /* USER CODE END Init */

 /* Configure the system clock */
 SystemClock_Config();

 /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

 /* USER CODE END SysInit */

 /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
 MX_GPIO_Init();
 MX_USART2_UART_Init();
 MX_I2C1_Init();
 MX_TIM3_Init();
 MX_TIM16_Init();
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
 HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim16, TIM_CHANNEL_1 );//incjalizuje timer16 chanel1 jako pwm output
   HAL_TIM_Encoder_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_ALL);
   disp.addr= (0x27<<1);
   disp.bl= true;
   lcd_init(&disp);
   sprintf((char*)disp.f_line,"costam");
   sprintf((char*)disp.s_line,"dziala");
   lcd_display(&disp);
         //char msg[64];
       set_ang(500);
       //uint8_t oldcount=0;
       menu_refresh(&disp);

 /* USER CODE END 2 */

 /* Infinite loop */
 /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
 while (1)
 {   menu_next();
     menu_refresh(&disp);
     HAL_Delay(1000);
   /* USER CODE END WHILE */

   /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

 /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
}
```

menu.h:

```
#ifndef MENU_H_
#define MENU_H_

typedef struct menu_struct menu_t;

struct menu_struct {

    const char * name;
    menu_t * next;
    menu_t * prev;
    menu_t * child;
    menu_t * parent;
    void (*menu_function)(void);

};

menu_t menu1;
    menu_t sub_menu1_1;//servo na przycisk
menu_t menu2;
    menu_t sub_menu2_1;//servo z ruchem
    menu_t sub_menu2_2;
    menu_t sub_menu2_3;
    menu_t sub_menu2_4;
menu_t menu3;
    menu_t sub_menu2_5;//mryganie diody
menu_t menu4;
menu_t menu5;
menu_t menu6;

void menu_refresh(struct lcd_disp * lcd);
void menu_next(void);
void menu_prev(void);
void menu_enter(void);
void menu_back(void);

#endif /* MENU_H_ */
```

menu.c:

```
#include <string.h>

#include "lcd_i2c.h"


#include "menu.h"

#include <stdio.h>

// definition of menu's components: (*name, *next, *prev, *child, *parent, (*menu_function))
menu_t menu1 = { "Servo1", &menu2, &menu5, &sub_menu1_1, NULL, NULL };
    menu_t sub_menu1_1 = { "ruchserwem", NULL, NULL, NULL, &menu1, NULL };
menu_t menu2 = { "Servo2", &menu3, &menu1, &sub_menu2_1, NULL, NULL };
    menu_t sub_menu2_1 = { "ruchserwem", &sub_menu2_2, &sub_menu2_4, NULL, &menu2, NULL };
    menu_t sub_menu2_2 = { "nic1", &sub_menu2_3, &sub_menu2_1, NULL, &menu2, NULL };
    menu_t sub_menu2_3 = { "nic2", &sub_menu2_4, &sub_menu2_2, NULL, &menu2, NULL };
    menu_t sub_menu2_4 = { "nic3", &sub_menu2_1, &sub_menu2_3, NULL, &menu2, NULL };

menu_t menu3 = { "diodwa", &menu4, &menu2, NULL, NULL,NULL};
menu_t menu4 = { "DUZE NIC1", &menu5, &menu3, NULL, NULL, NULL };
menu_t menu5 = { "DUZE NIC2", &menu1, &menu4, NULL, NULL, NULL };

menu_t *currentPointer = &menu1;
menu_t *nextPointer = &menu2;
uint8_t menu_index=0;



void menu_refresh(struct lcd_disp * lcd) { // lcd_refresh();
    sprintf((char*)(lcd->f_line),currentPointer->name);
    if(!currentPointer->next)
    {   sprintf((char*)(lcd->s_line)," ");}
    else
    {   sprintf((char*)(lcd->s_line),nextPointer->name);}

    lcd_display(lcd);
    //change_cursor(lcd,4);
    }

void menu_next() {
    if(!currentPointer->next)
    {return ;
    }
    else
    {   menu_index++;
        currentPointer=currentPointer->next;
        nextPointer=currentPointer->next;
    }

}

void menu_prev(void) {

    if(!currentPointer->prev)
    {   return ;
    }
    else
    {   menu_index++;
        nextPointer=currentPointer;
        currentPointer=currentPointer->prev;
    }
}

void menu_enter(void) {

    if(!currentPointer->child)
    {   return ;
    }
    else
    {   currentPointer=currentPointer->child;
    }


}

void menu_back(void) {
    if(!currentPointer->parent)
    {   return ;
    }
    else
    {   currentPointer=currentPointer->parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot put defintions in a header file - like `uint8_t menu_index=0;`. They must be in their own c file

Comment: what do you mean by that.  I completely deleted  menu_index variable and i still get problem . Could you explain in more detail ?

Comment: you have to remove all variable definitions. Header files contains structs declaration,function declaration, constants...

Answer (score 0):

you must not define variables in header files.

take

```
 uint8_t menu_index=0;
```

and put in  it 'common.c'

then replace it in the header file with

```
 extern uint8_t menu_index;
```

do the same for allvariable defintions

Comment: Just to complete this answer, remember that include file aren't something special are just code that is included within many places. So it's a good place to put type and function declaration so your unit can compile even if some types and or function are not yet defined. Not so good for definitions because this will result in ambiguity as you will define the same thing many times each for every include. That is called by the linker  "duplicate symbols".

Comment: the point is that a header file is typically included in multiple compile units